# Is there any way to Play music as background service in playbook?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, blackberry, blackberry-playbook, background-music

I have made a music player for blackberry playbook and it is working fine .My problem is  I want to play the music as a background service so that if user switches between other app . my music would play continuously ..

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using this line as the first line of your application

```
QNXSystem.system.inactivePowerMode = QNXSystemPowerMode.THROTTLED;
```

From now your app will play sound while the app is in background and also when the playbook is on standby state.

Comment: thanks for the answer ... but when m using this code it says ": Native methods are not allowed in loaded code." ... I google it and tried all the available option on google .. but still getting the same error ..

Comment: Are you attempting to run this in AIR on the desktop or something?  It certainly won't work there.

Comment: yes .... so how do I compile it ? I need to compile it on desktop and convert it to .bar file then send that .bar file to my Playbook. That is how it works I think ??